# MYSQL/PHP: Select identical numbers in different rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP application where I load numbers from a MYSQL table composed this way:

`DATE       | BA1 | BA2 | BA3 | BA4 | BA5
08/01/2014    1     8     66    34    89
07/01/2014    45    32    1     48    67
06/01/2014    17    8     90    35    31
05/01/2014    19    12    75    31    64
04/01/2014    32    43    18    21    67
...`

And so forth.

At this point I have to find the repeating numbers in a max of 12 rows (12 rows one after the other).

In the example above I should be getting the numbers `1`, `8`, `32` and `67` (because this numbers appear in line 1, 2 and 5. If the numbers do not appear in the following 12 rows then the operation has to finish.

I'm using PHP and I'm not sure if the best way to achieve this is thru PHP once I loaded the MYSQL or if I can do it straight in MYSQL.

How do I go about this?

I have to load all of the numbers in arrays (one for each line) and then do a function, or should I just load some of the results in PHP?

Comment: Also 31 should be included in result set because it is repeated in 3rd and 4th row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php you can create 2 arrays one for numbers and one for identical numbers lets say your query will be

```
select * from table order by date limit 12
```

After getting results in php you can loop through the query results and find identical numbers as

```
$numbers=array();
$identicals=array();
foreach($results as $result){

    if (in_array($result['BA1'], $numbers)) {
    $identicals[]=$result['BA1'];
    }else{
    $numbers[]=$result['BA1'];
    }
/* same if else for BA2,BA3,BA4 and BA5 */
}

print_r($identicals);
```

Using Mysql only you can use `union all`

```
SELECT num FROM(
(SELECT BA1 num FROM table1 ORDER BY `DATE` LIMIT 12)
UNION ALL
(SELECT BA2 num FROM table1 ORDER BY `DATE` LIMIT 12)
UNION ALL
(SELECT BA3 num FROM table1 ORDER BY `DATE` LIMIT 12)
UNION ALL
(SELECT BA4 num FROM table1 ORDER BY `DATE` LIMIT 12)
UNION ALL
(SELECT BA5 num FROM table1 ORDER BY `DATE` LIMIT 12)
) a
GROUP BY num
HAVING COUNT(num) > 1
ORDER BY num
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ec84/1)